# How to use aapt and javac with Android Support Libraries?

Tags: javac, aidl, aapt, dx

Can anyone help me building Android Applications using tools(aapt, aidl, javac, dx, jarsigner) with Android Support Library(v4, v7 etc). Without ant or gradle.
Thanks.

Comment: Your best bet is to write a small "Hello World" style application using gradle, and then make it print out the commands that it uses, and then copy+modify the commands for your own project. The aapt commands in particular are pretty verbose and non-obvious.

Comment: Thanks @JesusFreke, gradlew is building fine without any error. It is not showing any details of commands like aapt or javac. What options can I use with gradlew to list these details?

Comment: I believe --debug shows the actual commands being run. Just be aware that the output is extremely verbose though.